# ASP Force Download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In PHP I can do: `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream")` and then anything that I output is downloaded instead of showing in the browser.

Is there a similar way to do this in ASP? I have seen about all the file streaming and such using ADODB.Stream, but that doesn't seem to work for me and always requires another file to load the content from.

Bit of an ASP noob, so go easy on me. :p All I want to do is have a script that outputs a CSV and that will force download instead of showing in the browser.

Thanks

**EDIT**

here is my script currently:

reportingForce.aspx.vb

```
Public Class reportingForce
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Dim FStream

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Chr(34) & "my output file.csv" & Chr(34))
    Response.Write("1,2,3,4,5" & vbCrLf)
    Response.Write("5,6,7,8,9" & vbCrLf)
  End Sub

End Class
```

reportingForce.aspx

```
Hello,World
```

Comment: If you are new to ASP I highly recommend learning ASP.net and steering clear of classic ASP.

Comment: whats the difference? I'm extremely new to ASP - just helping with an existing script. I think the script is using ASP.net, but I do appologise, I wasn't aware there was a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to change the "Content-disposition" response header to "attachment". You don't need to change the content type.

I believe you can do something like this in ASP:

`Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=whatever.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do both..

```
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Chr(34) & "my output file.csv" & Chr(34)
Response.Write "1,2,3,4,5" & vbCRLF
Response.Write "5,6,7,8,9" & vbCRLF
```

Comment: What does the `Response.Write` bit do? I've put my code up in my original post. That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: From the detail you've added I can see that you mixing asp.net with classic asp. The info I gave was for classic ASP only.